# Core Data Relationship from One Entity to Multiple Entities

Tags: ios, core-data

I have a scenario of this data model:

- **Plan** has user relationship

[image]

- **Activity** also have user relationship

[image]

So in **User** entity, I created:

- Relationship of this userID to Activity's user

[image]

but how could I add relationship of userID to Plan's?

---

I read that I need to create 2 children entities of **User**. Is this the best practice?

Maybe I can create this 2 children entities of **User**:

- **UserPlan**
- **UserActivity**

But how can I refer the inherited userID of each children in relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename relationships in **User** to *activity* and *plan* and connect accordingly.

Comment: If that way, so there will be 2 rows with blank activity for plan record and otherwise?

Comment: You need to connect your Plan and Activity to User with inverted relationships. So, leave Plan and Activity as they are and recreate new relationships in User as I suggest.

Comment: The relationship should refer to the object at the other end. Calling a relationship on a user object userID is just confusing. The relationship on plan could just be called `user` as well, and make the same change for activity.

Comment: _Certainly_ don't worry about blank rows or anything that may or may not be happening in the database. That's core data's job

Comment: Thanks all! 1 more question for jrturton, if you suggest that way, for naming best practice, the 2 relationships in User can be named as userPlan and userActivity?